# Magnitude of n-th factorial

Tags: factorial, recursion, approximation-theory, stirling-numbers, big-numbers

In connection with a riddle on [The Riddler](https://fivethirtyeight.com/tag/the-riddler/), I would like to know how to evaluate even crudely the order of magnitude of an iterated factorial like
$$(\ldots(9\underbrace{!)!\ldots)!}_{n\text{ factorials}}$$
Using Stirling's approximation does not get me very far:
\begin{align*}
9! &\approx 3^9\\
(9!)! &\approx (3^9/3)^{3^9}=3^{8\times 3^9}\\
&...
\end{align*}

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) will allow you to approximate it as a powertower

Comment: Similar, but way overkill: http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Tripent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me explain why the numbers in a power tower don't matter.  Let us compare these two:

$$3^{5^{5^5}}=10^{10^{10^a}}$$

$$5^{50\times5^{5^5}}=10^{10^{10^b}}$$

Clearly, we will have $a<b$, but by how much?  Well, take the log of each thrice, and you will find that

$$a\approx2.7$$

$$b\approx2.7$$

Indeed, the only things that truly matters is how tall the power towers are, which is why may use a crude Stirling approximation:

$$k!\approx k^k$$

Also, a quick symbolization:

$$k!_n=k\underbrace{!!!!\dots~ !}_n$$

And furthermore,

$$k!_n\approx k^{k^{k^{\dots}}}\bigg\}(n+1)\text{ powers}$$

In terms of [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation):

$$k!_n\approx k\uparrow\uparrow(n+1)$$

Comment: Indeed, I had started to realise the additional factors did not matter so much and hence the very first approximation I thought of $9^{9^{9^\vdots}}$ was given a first order solution!

Comment: Yes, the difference of a few numbers do not really matter when placed in the right places.

Comment: I am not sure how much it matters but a closer approximation is$$9\underbrace{!...!}_{n\text{ times}}=\underbrace{3^{3^{\vdots^{3^9}}}}_{n\ 3's}$$

Comment: Depends what your doing with the number.  If you need closer approximation for tighter bounds, then sure.